# Dialog dismiss on AsyncTask timeout

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dialog, timeout, dismiss

I'm starting **AsyncTask** for a network connection and I decided a 10 seconds **timeout** after that the task should be **canceled** in case of **network issues**:

```
final aTask record = new aTask();
record.execute();
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run() {
      if ( record.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING ) {
          record.cancel(true);
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error in handling recording: connection timeout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  }
}, 10000 );
```

I noticed that the **Spinner** dialog is always running after the async task is canceled. 
How can I **dismiss** that ?

Comment: add record.dismiss(); after completing your asynch task operation on run method

Comment: dismiss() is not a method of the AsyncTask record object

Comment: Is your code throwing any exception?

Comment: the method doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier thing was to add the dialog.dismiss() inside the Handler code:

```
        final aTask record = new aTask();
        record.execute();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              if ( record.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING ) {
                  record.cancel(true);
                  dialog.dismiss(); <----------------- ADDED HERE
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error in handling recording: connection       timeout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }
        }, 10000 );
```

Many thanks to all for the help

Comment: This is the best one since i was stumbling in many answers :)

Answer (score 1):

When you cancel a Asynctask she does not leave the doInBackground...

> Blockquote
>   A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

Just check isCancelled() once in a while:

```
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Comment: What could be the while condition ? in doInBackground I'm trying to establish an network connection, so if I use while(true) it will open many connections until the timer stops...

Comment: The while condition is a example. If you need cancel network connection use timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a `Dialog` globally something like

```
Dialog dlg;
```

In `onPreExecute` of your `AsynTask`

```
dlg = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dlg.show();
```

In `doInBackground`

```
if(this.isCancelled())
dlg.dismiss();
```

And In `onPostExecute` of your `AyncTask` do this

```
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              if ( this.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING ) {
                  if(dlg.isShowing())
                  dlg.dismiss();
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error in handling recording: connection timeout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }
        }, 10000 );
```

Or if you simply want to dismiss the dialog when `AsynTask` has done its job then inside `onPostExecute` just use `dlg.dismiss()`

**Info**

From the documentation of [AsynTask.isCancelled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled())

> Returns true if this task was cancelled before it completed normally. If you are calling cancel(boolean) on the task, the value returned by this method should be checked periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to end the task as soon as possible.

Comment: using if(this.isCancelled())
dlg.dismiss(); in doInBackground(), will be checked once ?

Comment: As you can see in **Info** section of my edited answer,if you use `AsynTask.cancel()` then only you need to bother much about `isCancelled()`.However as i suggested not to use `cancel()` anywhere, `isCancelled()` will return true only if this task was cancelled before it completed normally and it won't execute `onPostExecute` then.So you need to dismiss your dialog manually if task gets cancelled due to some reason.

Comment: So while `doInBackground` is running `isCancelled()` will be checked once.But i don't think you need to worry about that if all you want it to dismiss your dialog.

Comment: the handler code should be outside the onPostExecute, otherwise it can't check if the AsyncTask is alive or not... And id doInBackground where my code about the connection should be ? before or after the isCancelled() check ?

Answer (score 0):

have a global reference for you dialog like this.

```
Dialog d;
```

// now in your AsyncTask

```
Class MyTask extends AsyncTask{

  onPostExecute(){

     if(d!=null){
       d.dismiss(); // do this to dismiss once task finished
     }
  }

          @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       // keep doing this 
        if(this.isCancelled()){
            d.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: Does it work if the AsyncTask is canceled like: record.cancel(true); ? Can onPostExecute() recognize deleted task ?

Comment: no, it wont be called in Android 4+ os versions. for that you can check the same in doInbackground, if task has cancelled or not, else the logic which cancelles your task, in that logic itself, dismiss the dialog the same way it was being dismissed via onPostExecute.

Comment: how can I test many times in doInBackground if(this.isCancelled()) ?

Comment: no need to test multiple times, just before returning from doInBackground add the check i mentioned in my code.